# Would what happened in South Park (human centipede) be legal?

Tags: united-states, contract-law, terms-of-service

There's an episode of South Park where buried in the terms and agreement of iTunes, you agreed that Apple could forcibly make you into a human centipede. See: [image: South Park human centipede]

In the real world could this happen? They *did* agree to the terms and conditions which *did* include that.

Comment: Related, [The Human Centipede](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Human_Centipede_(First_Sequence)). I think South Park is parodying the Dutch horror film.

Answer (score 5):

In the real world, the contract could not be enforced, as being [unconscionable](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unconscionability). See [Williams v. Walker-Thomas Furniture Company](http://law.justia.com/cases/federal/appellate-courts/F2/350/445/74531/), 350 F.2d 445. This, from the ruling, seems particularly applicable to TOS conditions:

> Did each party to the contract, considering his obvious education or
>   lack of it, have a reasonable opportunity to understand the terms of
>   the contract, or were the important terms hidden in a maze of fine
>   print and minimized by deceptive sales practices